# Capture Mobile number

Tags: php, regex

Mobile Number is 11 characters long and the number always starts with 07.

I want to capture mobile number from the string.. few example below:

```
$String1 = "Text Text Text 07751 123 456 Text Text";
$String2 = "Text Text Text 07751 123456 Text Text"
$String3 = "Text Text Text 07751 123456. Text Text"
$String4 = "Text Text Text 07751123456, Text Text"
```

How can it be done in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You could strip all non-numeric chars using:

```
function remove_non_numeric($string) {
   return preg_replace('/\D/', '', $string)
}
```

With that check it starts with `07` etc.

Comment: `We woke up at 7:00 and than we tried to call him 7 times, is this number: ..., still good?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$numbers = array();
preg_match_all('/[0-9\\- ]{6,}/', $string, $numbers);
print_r($numbers);
```

It should match all numbers made of five (you can adjust this) or more 0-9, dash and space characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\b(?<myNumber>07[\d\s]+?)(?=[^\d\s])/
```

edit: if you can say 'there may be spaces in the number, but 2 at most', you could add range (accounting for the trailing space) that pseudo validates the length:

```
/\b(?<myNumber>07[\d\s]{9,12})(?=[^\d\s])/
```

"word boundary, followed by a series of spaces/numbers starting with 07 (myNumber) having at most 14 total characters (11+3 spaces), but look-ahead at the end of that to see a non-digit,non-space (a letter or a dot in the data) so that we know we got the whole number". (and then remove spaces from your result)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking probably for regexp which will start with `07` and than have 9 numbers + some spaces... You can build either regexp that would just eat everything that it finds (containing spaces and `\d` (decimal numbers).

```
~07[\d\s]+~
```

Or build real regexp which will match only mentioned formats:

```
~07\d{3}\s*\d{3}\s*\d{3}~
```

All of those are arguments for `$pattern` in [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: How to much sure the number is 11 digit?

Comment: @user791022 `+` = `<1,oo>` up to memory limit (should match at least few kilobytes), that means `070000000                0               0    00000000000000000000000 000....` :) the second one specifies: 07, than 3 numbers, than `<0-oo>` spaces, than again 3 numbers, again spaces and again 3 numbers

Answer (score 0):

I am using PCRE type RegExs. You want to capture the possibility that spaces, periods, and commas may show up. Hence you can match this them and also make boundaries of spaces and words.

```
\s(07(\d+\s*)*)(\.|,|\s(\w))

\s = <space>
() = match group, also used for the numbered replacement expression
\d = digit
\. = literal period
| = logical or. So A or B is (A|B)
\w = word character, any alpha character
```

I tested this with a replacement expression of \s\1\s

Results

```
"Text Text Text 07751 123 456 ext Text"; <---replaced. See the missing "T"
"Text Text Text 07751 123 456 Text Text"; <--original

"Text Text Text 07751 123456 ext Text" <---replaced. See the missing "T"
"Text Text Text 07751 123456 Text Text" <--original

"Text Text Text 07751 123456  Text Text" <---replaced. See the missing "."
"Text Text Text 07751 123456. Text Text" <--original

"Text Text Text 07751123456  Text Text" <---replaced. See the missing ","
"Text Text Text 07751123456, Text Text" <--original

"Text Text Text 07751 123 456 ext Text"; <---replaced. See the missing "T"
"Text Text Text 07751 123 456 Text Text"; <--original
```